# How to get values from a JSON file as a string in Pyspark/ Spark SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file that looks like below

{"Name":"Fullname","Address":"FullAddress"},

this json comes in as an input from an external application and can vary over time, for example, I may get something like below as next input:

{"Name":"Fullname","Address":"FullAddress","Age":"DOB"},

What I need is to extract the values from the key:value pair as string, similar to 'Fullname,FullAddress,DOB,..,...' and so on depending upon how many values I get in the JSON.

These values map to columns in Hadoop tables, once I have the string, I can use that to write a spark sql query to get the values from underlying tables.

Comment: Load your json into a dataframe, pretty easy from there.

Comment: I am a noobie, however I have the dataframe part sorted-out, struggle is to create a string of comm separated values from the dataframe and that too specifically for the value part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`concat_ws/concat/array_join`** functions to concat all the column values into string.

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
df.show()
#+--------+-----------+---+
#|    Name|    Address|Age|
#+--------+-----------+---+
#|fullname|fulladdress|dob|
#+--------+-----------+---+
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
cols=[x for x in df.columns]

df.select(concat_ws(',',*cols).alias("str")).show(10,False)
#or
df.withColumn("str",array_join(array(*cols),",")).drop(*df.columns).show(10,False)
#+--------------------------------+
#|str                             |
#+--------------------------------+
#|fullname,fulladdress,dob        |
#+--------------------------------+
```

---

**`In Scala:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val cols= df.columns.map(x => col(x))
df.select(concat_ws(",",cols:_*).alias("str")).show(false)
//or
df.withColumn("str",concat_ws(",",cols:_*)).drop(df.columns:_*).show(false)
df.withColumn("str",array_join(array(cols:_*),",")).drop(df.columns:_*).show(10,false)

//+------------------------+
//|str                     |
//+------------------------+
//|fullname,fulladdress,dob|
//+------------------------+
```

**`For keys:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

keys=",".join(df.columns)

df.withColumn("keys",lit(keys)).show()
```

Comment: Can the same be done for key names as well? like 'Name,Address,Age,...,..'

Comment: @Prashant, check my updated answer `For Keys` section!